# Specific Bubble Sort Process

Tags: sorting, loops, bubble-sort

I'm reviewing for an exam, one of the practice questions is as follows:

*give the contents of the array after two iterations of the bubble sort (assume the lowest values are selected first to the left of the array*

43  16  99  12  48  14  62

The given answer is:

12  14  43  16  99  48    62

I have been reviewing my notes trying to figure out why this is the correct answer, but I have no idea why. I have found examples of the bubble sort on google and wikipedia and while those make sense to me, they are also very simple, this is more difficult.

Can someone please explain how 12  14  43  16  99  48    62 is the answer?

Comment: The answer looks more like a selection sort to me... sometimes professors are wrong...?

Comment: That's odd, I get 16 12 43 14 48 62 99 :)

Comment: The answer is to iterate *from the right*. You get the given answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I puzzled about this for a minute because indeed, it was hard to see, but once you realize how they're doing it, it's simple enough. Still, it's dumb.

We're sorting so that the lowest numbers are on the left, but we're *iterating from the right.* So the very first test is comparing 14 and 62, and not swapping; then comparing 48 and 14, and swapping; then 12 and 14, and doing nothing, etc. Once you get to the left end, go back to the right end and do a second pass, and you'll end up with the given solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining that Ernest, your knowledge and perspective are greatly appreciated! It does make sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this does not give the same answer as your teacher, but this is (I hope) a clear explanation of a bubble sort:

Because a picture is often a lot better than words: http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Bubble_sort

In your case, after the first iteration:

43 > 16 => **16 43** 99 12 48 14 62

43 < 99 => 16 **43 99** 12 48 14 62

99 > 12 => 16 43 **12 99** 48 14 62

99 > 48 => 16 43 12 **48 99** 14 62

99 > 14 => 16 43 12 48 **14 99** 62

99 > 62 => 16 43 12 48 14 **62 99**

Second Iteration:

16 < 43 => **16 43** 12 48 14 62 99

43 > 12 => 16 **12 43** 48 14 62 99

43 < 48 => 16 12 **43 48** 14 62 99

48 > 14 => 16 12 43 **14 48** 62 99

48 < 62 => 16 12 43 14 **48 62** 99

62 < 99 => 16 12 43 14 48 **62 99**

Comment: Thanks J_D, you've confirmed that I was doing this the right way (at least in our minds), because that was the answer that I was continually getting. I appreciate your answering my question